# Is there a way to fill the height in Tailwind even when I reduce de height of the browser?

Tags: tailwind-css

I have an issue when I reduce the size of the browser and scroll bar comes in, the body background stops at the height of the browser screen and under scroll is white.

I have tried with h-screen, h-full in the boby tag but with no result. Also on Tailwind I couldn't find anything.

Thank you.

```
  <body class="font-sans bg-gray-100  h-screen">
    <div>
      <!-- Left Sidebar -->
    <div class="flex h-screen bg-gray-800 text-white"> 
      <!-- Sidebar Content -->
      <div class="w-64 bg-gray-700">
        <!-- Sidebar Header -->
        <div class="flex items-center justify-start p-4">
          <h1 class="text-2xl font-semibold text-text-green">Test</h1>
        </div>
        <!-- Sidebar Links -->
        <nav class="p-4">
        </nav>
      </div>

      <!-- Main Content -->
      <div class="flex-1 p-4">
        <!-- Your main content goes here -->
        <div class="main-header">
          <div class="mb-0">
            <div class="relative mb-0 flex w-full flex-wrap items-stretch">
              <!--Search icon-->
              <span
                class="input-group-text flex items-center whitespace-nowrap rounded px-3 py-1.5 text-center text-base font-normal text-neutral-700 dark:text-neutral-200"
                id="basic-addon2"
              >
                <svg
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                  fill="var(--icon-color)"
                  class="h-5 w-5"
                >
                  <path
                    fill-rule="evenodd"
                    d="M9 3.5a5.5 5.5 0 100 11 5.5 5.5 0 000-11zM2 9a7 7 0 1112.452 4.391l3.328 3.329a.75.75 0 11-1.06 1.06l-3.329-3.328A7 7 0 012 9z"
                    clip-rule="evenodd"
                  />
                </svg>
              </span>
              <input
                type="search"
                class="relative m-0 block min-w-0 flex-auto rounded bg-transparent bg-clip-padding px-3 py-[0.25rem] text-base font-normal leading-[1.6] text-neutral-700 outline-none transition duration-200 ease-in-out focus:z-[3] focus:border-primary focus:text-neutral-700 focus:shadow-[inset_0_0_0_1px_rgb(59,113,202)] focus:outline-none dark:border-neutral-600 dark:text-neutral-200 dark:placeholder:text-neutral-200 dark:focus:border-primary"
                placeholder="Search..."
                aria-label="Search"
                aria-describedby="button-addon2"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="login">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h2 class="text-2xl font-semibold mb-4">Main Content</h2>
        <p>This is where your main content goes.</p>
        <h2 class="text-2xl font-semibold mb-4">Main Content</h2>
        <h2 class="text-2xl font-semibold mb-4">Main Content</h2>
        <h2 class="text-2xl font-semibold mb-4">Main Content</h2>
        <h2 class="text-2xl font-semibold mb-4">Main Content</h2>
        <h2 class="text-2xl font-semibold mb-4">Main Content</h2>
        <h2 class="text-2xl font-semibold mb-4">Main Content</h2>      
    </div>  
  </body>
</html> ``
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider removing the `height: 100vh` from the top-level elements, including the `<body>` element. This allows the elements to stretch in height and be tall enough to encompass their content. This in turn means their background colors will render for more of the vertical space.

To keep the behavior that the background colors should still cover the screen for taller viewports, consider applying `min-height: 100vh` on the sidebar element via the `min-h-screen` class:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<body class="font-sans bg-gray-100">
  <div>
    <!-- Left Sidebar -->
    <div class="flex bg-gray-800 min-h-screen text-white">
      <!-- Sidebar Content -->
      <div class="w-64 bg-gray-700">
        <!-- Sidebar Header -->
        <div class="flex items-center justify-start p-4">
          <h1 class="text-2xl font-semibold text-text-green">Test</h1>
        </div>
        <!-- Sidebar Links -->
        <nav class="p-4"></nav>
      </div>

      <!-- Main Content -->
      <div class="flex-1 p-4">
        <!-- Your main content goes here -->
        <div class="main-header">
          <div class="mb-0">
            <div class="relative mb-0 flex w-full flex-wrap items-stretch">
              <!--Search icon-->
              <span class="input-group-text flex items-center whitespace-nowrap rounded px-3 py-1.5 text-center text-base font-normal text-neutral-700 dark:text-neutral-200" id="basic-addon2">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="var(--icon-color)" class="h-5 w-5">
                  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M9 3.5a5.5 5.5 0 100 11 5.5 5.5 0 000-11zM2 9a7 7 0 1112.452 4.391l3.328 3.329a.75.75 0 11-1.06 1.06l-3.329-3.328A7 7 0 012 9z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                </svg>
              </span>
              <input type="search" class="relative m-0 block min-w-0 flex-auto rounded bg-transparent bg-clip-padding px-3 py-[0.25rem] text-base font-normal leading-[1.6] text-neutral-700 outline-none transition duration-200 ease-in-out focus:z-[3] focus:border-primary focus:text-neutral-700 focus:shadow-[inset_0_0_0_1px_rgb(59,113,202)] focus:outline-none dark:border-neutral-600 dark:text-neutral-200 dark:placeholder:text-neutral-200 dark:focus:border-primary" placeholder="Search..." aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="button-addon2" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="login"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h2 class="text-2xl font-semibold mb-4">Main Content</h2>
        <p>This is where your main content goes.</p>
        <h2 class="text-2xl font-semibold mb-4">Main Content</h2>
        <h2 class="text-2xl font-semibold mb-4">Main Content</h2>
        <h2 class="text-2xl font-semibold mb-4">Main Content</h2>
        <h2 class="text-2xl font-semibold mb-4">Main Content</h2>
        <h2 class="text-2xl font-semibold mb-4">Main Content</h2>
        <h2 class="text-2xl font-semibold mb-4">Main Content</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```